# In swift, is there a way to compare button images using button tag

Tags: ios, swift

I'm an amateur at swift and I have been trying to make a tic-tac-toe game. So I'd like to know if there is any way to compare button images using button tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate? show some code you tried to implement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a better way to approach this.

Do not try to compare buttons' images. Instead what you should do is to create a *model*. A model is basically something that represents a more complex system with simpler data structures.

In a tic-tac-toe game, instead of dealing with buttons, you can create such an enum:

```
enum SqaureContent {
    case empty, nought, cross
}
```

Your model will then be a 2D array of `SqaureContent`:

```
var gameBoard: [[SquareContent]] = [
    [.empty, .empty, .empty],
    [.empty, .empty, .empty],
    [.empty, .empty, .empty]
]
```

When the user taps on a button, the view controller can handle the tap by setting the button's image and also setting a value in the model to `.cross`. This way you can synchronise the model with the buttons (the "view").

Then, you can do all your operations on the model instead of the buttons.

You can then compare the values like this:

```
if gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][0] && gameBoard[1][0] == gameBoard[2][0] {
    ...
}
```

You know that this is going to be the same as comparing the button images because the model and the view is synchronised.

The benefit of writing programs this way is that you avoid a lot of complications. Buttons are complex objects. Their images can be anything, not just noughts and crosses. We should limit the values to just 3 - `.empty`, `.nought`, `.cross` using an enum.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can compare Image like that:

```
if yourCell.ButtonOutlet.currentImage.isEqual(UIImage(named: "yourImageName")) {

        } else {

        }
```